# Returning Bool to AJAX request

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

This must be a really simple answer, but i cannot see where I am going wrong.

Just typing a test AJAX request with c# code behind. I cannot get the c# to return a true/false statement, or I cannot get the AJAX to recognise it as true/false.

```
  [WebMethod]
    public static bool testme(int testnumber)
    {
        if (testnumber < 12)
        {
            return true;             }
        else
        {

            return false;
                }

    }
```

AJAX:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#test').click(function () {
               $.ajax({
                   type: "post",
                    url: "WebForm1/testme",
                    data: { testnumber: 13 },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data) {
                            console.log("true");
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("false");
                        }
                    },
                    Error:function(error){
                        console.log("error");
                    }
                });
            });
        })


    </script>
```

Button:

```
<input type="button" id="test" value="click me"/>
```

The console.log is showing true, even though the number I am entering is greater than 12, which should return the "false" bool from the c# method.

[image: console.log is returning a full page render see picture]

Comment: possible that the datatype needs to be bool instead of JSON?

Comment: nope, that just stops the whole AJAX request, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it was relativly simple, but not sure why it needs to be done. I got help from [https://forums.asp.net/t/2023743.aspx?Ajax+Webmethod+not+firing+](https://forums.asp.net/t/2023743.aspx?Ajax%20Webmethod%20not%20firing%20)

I needed to change
//settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
to

settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;

to my RouteConfig.cs and then everything worked fine.

If anyone knows why this isn't automatically changed when you add the System.Web.Services; or what this means i would love to know, anyway, all working great now.

Answer (score 0):

your `if(data)` check is checking truthiness, `data` is going to be an object, so look at it's properties and you can find C#'s result.

If you're unfamiliar with JS truthiness, look it up for a better description: but each variable is considered to be truthy if it has a valid value, if it's null or undefined (or 0 or '') then it will not be considered truthy and will fail a boolean check.

Comment: so what would the code be for checking the properties, i have tried data.properties but i cannot find the overload method? any help?

Comment: I tend to just use `console.log(data);` and in the developer tools you should be able to inspect it

Comment: the problem with this, is console.log(data) give me the full page script in the developer tools console, not a single result

Comment: look to @MitchelSellers for help, I don't have experience with C# backends,  in my experience it has either been a routing issue or a bad request

Comment: thanks, hopefuly it is simple and i'm doing something stuipdly wrong

Answer (score 0):

When you get a response from a WebMethod like this you have to use a .d to reference the value.  Your current code simply checks to see if you got a response, and most likely always evaluates to true.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#test').click(function () {
               $.ajax({
                   type: "post",
                    url: "WebForm1/testme",
                    data: { testnumber: 13 },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.d) {
                            console.log("true");
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("false");
                        }
                    },
                    Error:function(error){
                        console.log("error");
                    }
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
```

One pointer as well that can help you figure out what is going on would be to use the network tab of you browsers developer tools (F-12) to see the response format that is coming back from the server.  It isn't just returning true or false it is returning `d: true` or `d: false` thus the change I mentioned.

Comment: that still doesn't work, getting false returns now, even though i have changed the "test number" to 11

Comment: Is the proper value coming back via developer tools?  (Can you post the return that you see there)

Comment: via developer tools, if i console.log(data.d) i am getting undefined, if i console.log(data) i am getting the full page script in the console

Comment: Ok, that helps pinpoint it, it sounds like you are not properly getting to the web-method, but actually a full page render

Comment: for the URL, i am using WebForm/testme (which is the name of the method) how else should I get to the method?

Comment: any further thoughts @MitchelSellers

Comment: i have added a screen shot of the console when the button is pressed in the OP

Comment: I've found it, look at answer below

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have to use Ajax, I return from the function JSON object. 
For e.g:

```
return Json(new { result = true });
```

and in AJAX:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#test').click(function () {
               $.ajax({
                   type: "post",
                    url: "WebForm1/testme",
                    data: { testnumber: 13 },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.result === true) {
                            console.log("true");
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("false");
                        }
                    },
                    Error:function(error){
                        console.log("error");
                    }
                });
            });
        })


  </script>
```